# Minus sign in Feynman's The reason for antiparticles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, feynman-diagrams, probability, antimatter

I was going through Feynman's lecture on "The reason for antiparticles", which can be found [here](https://www.nucleares.unam.mx/%7Ealberto/apuntes/feynman.pdf), and I got a little confused early on. His statement of Eq. 3 seems clear to me, from which Eq. 5 follows directly. But then he says that from that an Eq. 8 one can derive the relation depicted in Fig. 3. I'm missing how do you get that minus sign. If you substitute Eq. 5 on the first term of Eq. 8, you get $$1 - 2 \Re(\beta) +\sum P_{\varphi_0 \rightarrow p} =1,$$ but then the $1$'s cancel aout and you get  $$ 2 \Re(\beta) =\sum P_{\varphi_0 \rightarrow p},$$ which has the opposite sign as that it the picture. What went wrong? Here I'm using $\beta$ to summarize that long integral he writes down. Is it something subtle like distinguishing between "not doing anything" $P_{\varphi_0 \rightarrow \varphi_0}$ and actually scattering twice but ending up looking *as if* you did nothing $P_{\varphi_0 \rightarrow p \rightarrow \varphi_0}$?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of being in some state or another at the end of the interactions is $1$. Equation (5) gives the probability of being in the state $\phi_0$ after the two interactions. Then equation (8) gives the probability of being either in state $\phi_0$ or another state, which is $p$. So equation (8) there is
$$
\text{Prob}_{\phi_0\rightarrow\phi_0}+ \int\text{Prob}_{\phi_0\rightarrow p}= 1\\
1+\int\text{Prob}_{\phi_0\rightarrow\phi_0}\text{via p}+\int\text{Prob}_{\phi_0\rightarrow p}= 1.\\
$$
So to get the mysterious equivalence, rearrange the above to remove the $1$s.

I think the thing that you missed is where it says $\langle\phi_0|\phi_0\rangle=1$.

Comment: thanks, I'm almost there. I got the equivalence using both of the equations you wrote. The first one is Eq. 8, but how do you write the second line?

Comment: @Danyel it is just the probability of staying the same and the probability of changing and going back to the same state.

Comment: I see! Just from a physics point of view, if the probability of staying the same is already 1, then how come anything else than that could ever happen?